# What's the tops function in haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, hugs

In the final exam of a functional programming subject in my university, there was a question with a code listing that used a function called **tops**.

I can't find anything about that function in the official textbooks, [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=tops), the [prelude index](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/prelude-index.html), nor [the](http://cheatsheet.codeslower.com/CheatSheet.pdf) [damn](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/index.html) [internets](https://www.google.es/search?q=haskell%20%22tops%20function%22), and my hugs interpreter doesn't seem to recognize it (WinHugs 98, v. september 2006), even with hugs extensions enabled, either.

I'm guessing it's some kind of deprecated function from a very old version. Anyone knows better what is this tops function, or even if does it really exists?

**Update:**

I have found a copy of the exam. This is the question:

1. What does the function whatdoido calculate?

> ```
> whatdoido [] = [[]]
> whatdoido (x:xs) = concat [[x:t] | t <- tops xs]
> ```

Comment: so what did it do? (this might be too localized)

Comment: @jberryman, that's exactly what I want to know.

Comment: It's not in the standard libraries, [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) doesn't know it either. I suspect it was defined in the question.

Comment: No, Daniel Fischer, it wasn't. I wonder if it was an error on the teachers side.

Comment: Can you reproduce the question here? If not, then there is likely no answer to this question (or perhaps the answer is just [mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question)).

Comment: Right now no, sorry. I will try to get my hands on it and then I will. And no, I don't think the answer was intended to be mu. But, who knows.

Comment: @JaimePardos sorry, "too localized" is one of the criteria for closing a question

Comment: @jberryman, I know, but how can this question be "too localized"? I want to know if a "tops" function exists or has existed in any standard version of haskell.

Comment: @JaimePardos I suppose if the answer to your question is "yes", then it may help some future code archaeologists who have the same question, but if the answer is "no, `tops` is something your prof defined" then "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors".

Comment: @jberryman: I see, you're right. I'll delete the question if nobody happens to know about the function in a reasonable time (say, 2-3 weeks max?)

Comment: @JaimePardos I would just let others close it if they feel one way or another about it. no big deal either way.

Comment: @jberryman: I don't have to "let" anyone close it, if it gets enough votes, it will be closed, whether I "let" them or not :) Yeah, no big deal, but I would like the question to have some time to be exposed, just in case.

Comment: First possibility: When renaming the function to `whatdoido`, one instance of its old name was forgotten. Second possibility: `tops` was defined in the exam or the course.

Comment: there's a "top" here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ralist/0.1.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-RAList.html   actually, there's also a "tops" there

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm positively sure tops was not defined in the exam nor in the course. The first possibility sounds quite plausible, though.

Comment: @groovy: Nice catch. It's a data type, however, with uppercase T.

Comment: @groovy But not a top-level exported entity of that name. I guess as local functions, most half-sensible names (and a lot of others) have been used at various points.

Comment: search "concat [ [x : t" in this exam: http://www.lcc.uma.es/~pepeg/pfHaskell/apendices/cap18.pdf    the function there bears a resemblance and does some kind of combinations.

Comment: Could it have been similar to `inits` ?

Comment: However I suspect that they just forgot to change the name, and it was supposed to be a recursive function.

Comment: @Wes, I find this a very likely possibility as well.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what we can deduce while we scrabble around to find what `tops` did.

```
whatdoido [] = [[]]
whatdoido (x:xs) = concat [[x:t] | t <- tops xs]
```

If we assume `(x:xs)::[a]` then `[x:t]::[[a]]` so `concat [[x:t] | t <- tops xs] :: [[a]]` and also `tops xs :: [[a]]` so `tops :: [a] -> [[a]]` for some possibly polymorphic/monomorphic/class-restricted type `a`.

Clearly then, the function `whatdoido` takes the tail of its input, runs `tops` on that and pops the head of its input in front of each list returned by `tops`.

In particular, it's been suggested that `tops` is just a typo for `whatdoido`, in which case the base equation would mean `whatdoido xs = [xs]`.

Another suggestion is that `tops` is a typo for `tails` from `Data.List`. It's a surprisingly well-spelt typo if, so, but in that case you get behaviour like `whatdoido "Hi!" = ["Hi!", "H!", "H"]`.

Comment: Good answer, I don't know why I didn't think of approaching it this way.

Comment: Nice approach. Not really much new info, though. I don't think it's a typo for tails.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to hoogle, another place to search is [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html). I can't find a `tops` function there either, so I suspect it was a function your teacher defined elsewhere. However, hayoo and hoogle don't index every package in the Hackage DB, so it is possible that it is defined in a module on Hackage.

Comment: From http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html: Hayoo! will search **all packages** from Hackage, including **all function and type definitions**. (emphasis mine)